# Trying to retrieve part of URL with jQuery; it works, but a string isn't returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, search

Background info:  I'm setting up a way to embed SoundCloud's HTML5 widget on my forum.  The widget, on its own, adjusts its content in accordance with its height.  As you can see in the jsFiddle example below, I have it set up so that when a widget is hovered over, it expands from 166px to 450px in height, which triggers the widget to adjust its content.

The problem I'm trying to fix is that all SoundCloud widgets fold out, whether they're part of a set/playlist or not.  If it isn't part of a set/playlist, the result is a large blank area when hovered over.

I've noticed that if a sound is part of a set/playlist, /sets/ is present in the URL.  I'm trying to modify my script so that it checks the URL for that string.  If it finds it, allow the widget to expand when hovered over; if it doesn't, don't allow it to expand when hovered over.

Currently I'm at a roadblock.  It works, but the search is returning the position in the line, rather than the string I need.  I added a little bit of code to demonstrate that:

http://jsfiddle.net/TYWUf/11/

JS without the extra code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    var soundSrc = $(".soundCloudEmbed").attr("src");
    var isSet = (soundSrc).search('%' + '2Fsets' + '%' + '2F');

    $(".soundCloudEmbed").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).addClass("soundCloudHover");
        }, function () {
            $(this).removeClass("soundCloudHover");
    });
});
```

(if I didn't ask this question correctly, please let me know)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out, I think it's what you're looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/dSX5g/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    $('.soundCloudEmbed').each(function () {
        var soundSrc = $(this).attr("src");
        var isSet = (soundSrc).search('%' + '2Fsets' + '%' + '2F');

        if (isSet > -1) {
            $(this).hover(function () {
                $(this).addClass("soundCloudHover");
            }, function () {
                $(this).removeClass("soundCloudHover");
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Each embedded item needs to be evaluated separately.

Comment: It looks like what you did was set it up to check if the value returned by the search is above 0 (indicating that the string exists) or not (indicating that it doesn't).  I'm kicking myself for not thinking of that.  Seriously, thank you!  So far your solution seems to be working perfectly on my forum.

Comment: Not a problem. For future reference, if you have an "`indexOf`"-type function that searches for the position of a substring in a string, it will return -1 if the substring isn't found.

Answer (score 0):

You are manually setting the class as an html attribute, and then using a JQuery selector to expand anything in that class.  You should start out by looping through your iframes and setting different classes based on if it's part of a set or not.   That way the JQuery selector will only expand those classes that are sets.